# android pass color variable to a complex button style in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-button, android-styles

I have a style for button like : http://ace-subido.github.io/css3-microsoft-metro-buttons/buttons.html (See Stripped button).
But I want to be able to use this style for different colors without recreating 4 xml files (a selector drawable + 3 button states drawables with layer list).

In a btn_stripped_orange.xml (and 2 other xml for different button states) I have a color

With this syntax, evrything is ok :-)

But instead of creating 4 new xml files for every different colors, I want to "pass a color" to btn_stripped_orange.xml (so I should rename it to btn_stripped.xml).

In style.xml I have to call @drawable/btn_stripped_orange_selector
after this btn_stripped_orange_selector call

I think I have to pass the border_color variable to the style in styles.xml with call @drawable/btn_stripped_orange_selector
I want to just create new style with the @drawable/btn_stripped_orange_selector as android:background (and rename it) and the color varaible

This is the code that I'm trying to do (no error in eclipse, but app crash on run), If I replace ?attr/border_color with a color @color/orange for exemple, it works perfectly. I think it's just a syntax problem.

My themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="btn_orange" parent="@style/btStripped1">
    <item name="border_color">@attr/border_color</item>
  </style>
  <attr name="border_color" format="color" />
</resources>
```

My btn_stripped_orange_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stripped_orange_press" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stripped_orange_focus" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_stripped_orange" />
</selector>
```

My btn_stripped_orange.xml (nearly the same than _focus and _press) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="?attr/border_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Finally in my styles.xml

```
 <resources> 
   .....
    <style name="btStripped1">
      <!-- I want to pass a color variable here -->
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_stripped_orange_selector</item>
      <item name="android:padding">6dp</item>
              <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
              <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/white</item>
              <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
              <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
              <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
        </style>
   ....
 </resources>
```

I want a pure xml solution but if it's impossible and you have a solution with a bit of java code, your're welcome !

Thank you very very much for your help and sorry for average english !

Comment: So what is your Question ? you want to pass a color resource into an XML file?

Comment: yes I want to pass a color ressource in styles.xml for the drawable btn_stripped_selector which includes 3 drawables (btn_stripped , btn_stripped_press , btn_stripped_focus), these 3 drawable have to use the color ressource.